# How can I create random operations with 2 features?

Tags: octave

Example: I have the feature Y and the feature X.

I want Octave to do Y (random operator) X.

Then repeat this, but with random operators, and registering the results as it is going on. Is this possible?

My trying:

```matlab
A = ['*';'+';'-';'/'];

for i:(1:10)
    op1 = A (randi([1 4]),1);
    op2 = A (randi([1 4]),1);
    op3 = A (randi([1 4]),1);
    op4 = A (randi([1 4]),1);
    op5 = A (randi([1 4]),1);
    op6 = A (randi([1 4]),1);
    result = 1 op1 4 op2 25 op3 2 op4 23 op5 6 op6 2
end
```

Comment: The only way it seems possible is with the bitter `eval` or the sugar-coated eval (`str2num`)

Comment: how would it be?

Comment: If you ever need to use them, it tells you that you should change how you approach the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution not involving the use of `eval` and `str2func` could be the use of an array of [anonymous functions](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

```
% Define the input values
v1=25
v2=5
% Define the array of anonymous functions, one for each operator
f={@(x,y) (x+y);
   @(x,y) (x-y);
   @(x,y) (x*y);
   @(x,y) (x/y)}
% Randomly call one of the anonymous functions
for i=1:10
   r=randi([1,4],1,1)
   result(i)=f{r}(v1,v2)
end
```

Comment: Instead you can define `f` as `f={@plus,@minus,@times,@rdivide};`

Comment: Applicable only if there are  two numbers and one operator at a time.